# Getting started with Bluetooth development for Android: Suggestions for test application

Tags: android, testing, bluetooth

I have a task to integrate a Bluetooth device into my application. Now my requirement is very specific. The device has a specific communication protocol which relies on certain ACKs but I figured it would make my development much easier if there was a program that let me test communication with the device.

I was wondering if there was a program for Linux, or perhaps a simple Android program which let me communicate with any Bluetooth device with a series of pings using data I enter and simply log the responses.

EDIT: I might not have been clear enough in my question.

I have a scale that I need to integrate into my application, and the scale has a protocol similar to this:

Get a specific byte string from device
Transfer data
Transfer packet for disconnection
Receive acknowledgement for disconnect packet
Disconnect

Now when I have to issue a POST request from my application, I usually build a test script online so I can test if the POST works properly.

I was wondering if there was something similar I could do with the device.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not clear enough. To communicate with a BT device, you need to know what profile your device supports. Depending on that, you can find a way in Android or Linux or windows to communicate with the device.

The simplest way is to open an RFCOMM channel from android/PC and transfer data to and from the device. For this the device has to support the serial port profile (SPP). If you want to do this in Android, look for the **BluetoothChat** example from google.

If you want to use a PC/mac/linux look at the **Bluez** python module. It's really simple to use. There are plenty of other options too..

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for something like SENA BTerm. It lets me connect to any device and send whatever data I wish.

It is an extremely useful tool for testing my code.

http://www.sena.com/download/manual_bterm/overview.html is where you can find it.